# Error adding my first migration in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to add an initial migration in my EF Core 6 Project in .NET6 but I get this error: Add-Migration: Exception calling "BuildProject" with "3" argument(s): "The method or operation is not implemented."

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of the projects isn’t able to build. So I build each one from the bottom up (I.e. one with no dependencies (domain), then data then the console app and Now it works fine